# How to write using BCP to a remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, command-line-interface, bcp, bulk-load

I have a remote SQL Server with a hostname I am using to connect to.

BCP suggests to use

```
bcp DBName.dbo.tablename in C:\test\yourfile.txt -c -T -t
```

However when I try this it does not connect to DBName as that is not a valid alias. I get native error 2.

How to I run BCP but specify an internet / network address to connect to, not an MSSQL server name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to I run BCP but specify an internet / network address to connect to, not an MSSQL server name?

You can specify the IP address (here just 127.0.0.1) instead of the server name.

`bcp DBName.dbo.tablename in "C:\test\yourfile.txt" -c -T -t -S"127.0.0.1\instance"`

If you truly want to go IP\port only then use IP address and port separated by comma

`bcp DBName.dbo.tablename in "C:\test\yourfile.txt" -c -T -t -S"127.0.0.1,60905"`

Of course in that case you would need to know the port the instance is using, and your instance should be set to use a fixed port

Comment: question: is the output file "yourfile.txt" go to the C: drive on the serve identified by the flag -S? or on the server running bcp?  so if I was running thedatabase.db.myhost.com, is C:\ on my machine? or on thedatabase.db.myhost.com?  Thanks

Comment: @arcee123. The output file is saved on the server running bcp. In fact, it would be impossible to save on the server identified by the flag -S, as the only access that is being granted to that server is database access, and not access to the windows (or whatever) environment,

Answer (score 2):

The DBName is the name of the database, you need to use -S option to provide the server (or server\instance) name.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx):

> -S server_name [\instance_name] Specifies the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. If no server is specified, the bcp utility
>   connects to the default instance of SQL Server on the local computer.
>   This option is required when a bcp command is run from a remote
>   computer on the network or a local named instance. To connect to the
>   default instance of SQL Server on a server, specify only server_name.
>   To connect to a named instance of SQL Server, specify
>   server_name\instance_name.

Comment: OP specifically says not to use the name of the server

Comment: That server name is the DNS name of the server, not the database name or instance name. I guess OP is mixing things up

Comment: I agree, Its more likely that they meant the instance name. I that case `SERVERNAME,port` undocumented server specification could be used