# how can write bcp select Without remotely accessing the server?

Tags: sql-server

i can connect to database with management studio but i cant remote to that windows.
how can write bcp "select" Without remotely accessing the server?
tanx

```
bcp "Select personelid, '13'+date date, scheduleid, scheduleGroupName, DetailCollectionID, Name, TimesStructure, DayNO, Sequence, WPID, ToleranceTimes, DayState, StructureID, ID, STime, ETime from framework.att.PersonDateStructure" queryout "D:\test\pds.txt" -T -c
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write using BCP to a remote SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655247/how-to-write-using-bcp-to-a-remote-sql-server)

Comment: @Mohammad; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample from your code :

```
bcp "Select personelid, '13'+date date, scheduleid, scheduleGroupName, DetailCollectionID, Name, TimesStructure, DayNO, Sequence, WPID, ToleranceTimes, DayState, StructureID, ID, STime, ETime from framework.att.PersonDateStructure" queryout "D:\test\pds.txt" -T -c -S 10.0.0.108 -U sa -P 0000
```

> My DB-Server address is 10.0.0.108 so change it plz, also put your
>   username and password

Latest BPC version : [Download here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2043518)

**-S server_name [\instance_name]**

Specifies the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. If no server is specified, the bcp utility connects to the default instance of SQL Server on the local computer. This option is required when a bcp command is run from a remote computer on the network or a local named instance. To connect to the default instance of SQL Server on a server, specify only server_name. To connect to a named instance of SQL Server, specify server_name\instance_name.

**-U login_id**

Specifies the login ID used to connect to SQL Server.

**-P password**

Specifies the password for the login ID. If this option is not used, the bcp command prompts for a password. If this option is used at the end of the command prompt without a password, bcp uses the default password (NULL).

Detail Info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#S

Comment: can you change my code?

Comment: @MohammadNaghsh : Check it again please.

Comment: i get this error
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'KASRA\mnaghsh'.

Comment: If you are sure about user/pass try -G parameter.